# UILineBreakModeWordWrap doesn't work with UITableViewCellStyleValue2. Please, see the screenshot

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

UILineBreakModeWordWrap doesn't work with UITableViewCellStyleValue2. Please see my screenshot.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"any-cell"];
 if(cell == nil)
 {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:@"any-cell"] autorelease];
 }
  cell.textLabel.text = @"Address";
  cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
  cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

  cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"1838 East Wardlow St (Corner of Cherry & Wardlow)";
  cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
  cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

   return cell;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: How is it not working? It's wrapping the line on words.

Comment: Text height is more than cell height. The cell looks ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` does actually work seeing your screenshot.

What's happening is that the height of your UITableViewCell is not big enough.

You can calculate the needed height and set it in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method of the TableView's delegate like so:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellText = @"1838 East Wardlow St (Corner of Cherry & Wardlow)";

    CGSize textSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:LABEL_FONT constrainedToSize:LABEL_SIZE lineBreakMode:LABEL_LINEBREAKMODE];

    return textSize.height; // Add margins accordingly
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 6 +  use NSLineBreakByWordWrapping instead of UILineBreakModeWordWrap.